# No consigo llevar los datos a FillForm

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Probe de todo haciendo bug y lo que intento es que algunos datos capturados de una planilla hoja Excel pase a ciertas celdas estáticas en la otra planilla de Google Sheets, sin embargo haciendo debug todo funciona bien en `onNewRow`, y cuando hago logger `realdata` captura la información, luego cuando hago logger en `fillform` `data`.  `PersonaAfectada` aparece `null`, es decir no envía esos datos a esa función, no tengo restricciones, esta funcionando bien el array, etc.

```javascript
function onNewRow() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXX').getSheetByName('Hoja 2');
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXX').getSheetByName('Reporte');

  var row = getLastUnprocessedRow(sourceSheet);
  Logger.log(row);
  if (row !== null) {
    var data = readData(sourceSheet, row);
   Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // Añade esta línea
    fillForm(targetSheet, data);
    
    sendEmail(targetSheet);
    markRowAsProcessed(sourceSheet, row);
  }
}
function getLastUnprocessedRow(sheet) {
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var processedColumn = lastColumn + 1; // Asume que la columna "Procesada" es la siguiente después de la última columna con datos
  
  for (var i = lastRow; i > 0; i--) {
    var processedCell = sheet.getRange(i, processedColumn).getValue();
    if (processedCell !== 'Procesada') {
      return i;
    }
  }
  
  return null;
}
function readData(sheet, row) {
  var data = {};
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var values = range.getValues()[0]; // Esta es la línea que faltaba
 Logger.log(values);
  data.personaAfectada = values[0];
  Logger.log(data.personaAfectada); // Asume que 'Persona afectada' está en la primera columna
  data.empresaAfectada = values[1]; // Asume que 'Empresa afectada' está en la segunda columna
   data.departamento = values[2]
   data.ciudad = values[3]
   data.estacion = values[4]
  data.ducto = values[5]
  data.campamento = values[6]
  data.lugarExacto =values[7]
  data.kp = values[8]
  data.poblacioncercana = values[9]
  data.fechaIncidente = values[10]
  data.horaIncidente = values[11]
  data.fechaHoraInforme = values[12]
  data.personas = values[13]
  data.bienes = values[14]
  data.impacto = values[15]
  data.producto = values[16]
  data.causa = values[17]
  data.cantidadLiquido = values[18]
  data.cantidadGas = values[19]
  data.reputacion = values[20]
  data.incidente = values[21]
  data.consecuencias = values[22]
  data.causas = values[23]
  data.defensa = values[24]
  data.datosRelevantes = values[25]
  return data;
}
function fillForm(data) {
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXX').getSheetByName('Reporte');
  var combinedValue = 'Impacto: ' + data.impacto + ', Producto: ' + data.producto + ', Causa: ' + data.causa + ', Cantidad de Líquido: ' + data.cantidadLiquido + ', Cantidad de Gas: ' + data.cantidadGas;
  
 Logger.log(data.personaAfectada);
 Logger.log(targetSheet.getName());
  targetSheet.getRange('B7:C7').setValue(data.personaAfectada);

 Logger.log(targetSheet.getRange('B7').getValue());
  targetSheet.getRange('D7:E7').setValue(data.empresaAfectada);
  targetSheet.getRange('F7:G7').setValue(data.ciudad);
  targetSheet.getRange('H7:I7').setValue(data.departamento);
  targetSheet.getRange('J7:K7').setValue(data.estacion);
  targetSheet.getRange('L7').setValue(data.ducto);
  targetSheet.getRange('M7:N7').setValue(data.campamento);
  targetSheet.getRange('B9:D10').setValue(data.lugarExacto);
  targetSheet.getRange('E9:F10').setValue(data.kp);
  targetSheet.getRange('G9:H10').setValue(data.poblacioncercana);
  targetSheet.getRange('I9:K9').setValue(data.fechaIncidente);
  targetSheet.getRange('J10:K10').setValue(data.horaIncidente);
  targetSheet.getRange('L9:N9').setValue(data.fechaHoraInforme);
  targetSheet.getRange('B13:D13').setValue(data.personas);
  targetSheet.getRange('E13:G13').setValue(data.bienes);
  targetSheet.getRange('H13:L13').setValue(combinedValue);
  targetSheet.getRange('M13:N13').setValue(data.reputacion);
  targetSheet.getRange('B15:N15').setValue(data.incidente);
  targetSheet.getRange('B17:N17').setValue(data.consecuencias);
  targetSheet.getRange('B19:N19').setValue(data.causas);
  targetSheet.getRange('B21:N21').setValue(data.defensa);
  targetSheet.getRange('A23:G29').setValue(data.datosRelevantes);
}
function sendEmail() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXX');
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ss.getId() + "&exportFormat=xlsx";

    var params = {
      method: "get",
      headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };

    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
    blob.setName(ss.getName() + ".xlsx");

    MailApp.sendEmail("", "Informe de incidente", "Por favor, encuentra adjunto el informe de incidente.", {attachments: [blob]});
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
}
function markRowAsProcessed(sheet, row) {
  var processedColumn = 27; // Columna 'AA' es la columna número 27
  sheet.getRange(row, processedColumn).setValue('Procesada');
}
```

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda  para la solución de un problema de código deben de incluir un [mcve]. Si bien la pregunta incluye código, este no incluye suficientes detalles, sin embargo, incluye demasiado código.